# converse of Weyl criterion

Tags: nt.number-theory, fourier-analysis

Let $f∈L^1([0,1))$,suppose for all equi-distributed sequence $\{a_n\}^∞_{n=1}$ in $[0,1)$,we have
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^Nf(a_k)=\int_0^1f.$$
Do we have that $f$ is Riemann integrable ?
Remark: I can just prove if $f$ satisfies the above equality, then $f$ must be bounded.

EDIT:
The statement of this problem seems to cause confusion here.Here the $L^1$ means a Lebesgue integrable function with finite integral of $|f|$ but not its equivalence up to a measure zero set.For example,$1_{[0,1)}$ and $1_{[0,1) \setminus \mathbb{Q}}$ are not the same here.

More precisely,you can replace the $L^1([0,1))$ by $\{f \text{ is a Lebesgue integrable function on [0,1) and } \int_0^1|f|<\infty\}$ in the question.

Comment: How can you even define such an average on $L^{1}$ function? $L^{1}$ functions, by definition, are defined almost-everywhere...

Comment: Maybe the OP means $\displaystyle{\lim_{\mu(N)\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{\mu(N)}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\tilde{f}(a_{k})}$ for the LHS, where $\tilde{f}(a_{k})=f(a_{k})$ if $f(a_{k})$ exists, and $\tilde{f}(a_{k})=0$ otherwise, and $\displaystyle{\mu(N):=\sum_{k=1}^{N}1_{"f(a_{k})\ \ exists"}}$.

Comment: I'd agree with @Asaf that there is both ill-definedness and un-natural-ness in asking about the left-hand side for merely-$L^1$ functions. Taking pointwise values, and/or adding them, is not ... reasonable. Also, one might argue that "Riemann-integrable" is not so natural as a property of distributions/functions, except historically-developmentally. If one insists, things in the direction of SylvainJulien's suggestion might be more natural, but, still, one might more-and-more decide that the question, while reasonable to start, is discovered to be somehow inaccurate...?

Comment: (Just so @SylvainJULIEN is notified, in case of interest...) Or, Lebesgue points? Maximal functions? such things.

Comment: It's not hard to define the problem:  Suppose $f$ is a function from $[0,1]$ to ${\Bbb R}$, and $f$ happens to be Lebesgue integrable.  If it satisfies the criterion of the problem, must it be Riemann integrable?  I don't see what is ill defined about this (and I also don't know how to answer it).

Comment: @Lucia, as the question is morally equivalent (in view of Lebsgue's thm) to the following question - is there a measure zero set which "avoids" any equidistributed sequence (in a proper manner, say the upper density of the intersection of the sequence with the set should be zero)? As such (maybe non-existent) set which would provide a counter-example should be pathological (zero dimensional?) one have to be careful in posing the analytic properties in question. 

Notice that this is not an ergodic average of some sort!

Comment: @Asaf: I agree that it's delicate.  I don't even fully know what I believe is correct.  But anyway the version as I understand it is a perfectly well defined problem.

Comment: Sorry to product any confusion.Here the L^1 means a Lebesgue integrable function with finite integral of $|f|$ but not its equivalence up to a measure zero set.This is exactly what @Lucia pointed out.Thank you.

Comment: @Ben, in this case, the proper notation should be $\mathcal{L}^{1}$ or something. Secondly, the function $x^{-0.5}$ is not contained in the scope of your question, although it's integrable (improper Riemann or Lebesgue) and makes a good density function, hence your question is very un-natural in this equidistribution setting. Anyways, the prototypical arugment for this sort of questions would be - assume the contrary, the set of discontinuities will be of positive measure, hence any equi-dist. sequence will spend positive denisty of its time inside it, and one should try to exploite that.

Comment: @Asaf: I disagree. The function $x^{-1/2}$ is in the scope of Ben's question, and it is not Riemann integrable (no matter how you define it at zero). As Ben says, it does not satisfy the condition either. The original question is quite natural.